# PyQt: Exit QSystemTrayIcon program after QMessageBox

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, taskbar

I have a simple script primarily based on `QSystemTrayIcon`. Everything works find, and there's an option there on right-click on the taskbar icon that exits the program. I would like to add a `QMessageBox`, and on choosing yes, exit the program; otherwise, do nothing.

I'm familiar with all that, but it doesn't work as it should, and hence the question. I created a minimal example to demonstrate the problem:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class SystemTrayIcon(QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, icon, parent)
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(parent)
        self.exit_action = self.menu.addAction("Exit")
        self.setContextMenu(self.menu)
        self.exit_action.triggered.connect(self.slot_exit)

        self.msg_parent = QtWidgets.QWidget()

    def slot_exit(self):
        reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self.msg_parent, "Confirm exit",
                                               "Are you sure you want to exit Persistent Launcher?",
                                               QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes, QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
        # if reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
        #     QtCore.QCoreApplication.exit(0)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    tray_icon = SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon("TheIcon.png"))

    tray_icon.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now you see, at the `slot_exit()` function, whether I choose yes or no, the program exits (with code 0, no errors). The commented part is what I expect to be used to determine the action based on the choice. Could you please help me figure out why this behavior is happening and what's the right way to exit only on "yes"?

I'm using Windows 10, 64-bit with Python Anaconda 3.5.2 32-bit, and PyQt 5.7.

Comment: Quite surprising no one even looked at this! I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I'm reluctant to call it a bug, but it sounds like one. Why would it exit just by answering a QMessageBox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that Qt is made to exit when all Windows are closed. Simply disable that with:

```
app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
```

in your `main()`.

Comment: That was it! Thanks!

Comment: Spent 3 days before finding this. I think my thread is wrong. Saved my day. I don't know why this question and answer get low attention.