# Pyqt5 threading can't work (Fatal Python error: could not acquire lock)

Tags: python, pyqt5, qthread

I have read bunch of QThread tutorials and SO Answers about this. But I can't make my threading works. Most of the time, it just run once or it print error message. Threading works if I started it immediately after the app start, but I want the thread to run after certain function, cause I want to set the directory location first.

The file structure is arranged like this:

```
App.py
Controllers/
    main_controller.py
    recorder.py
Model/
    model.py
Views/
    main_view.py
```

**App.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

from Model.model import Model
from Controllers.main_controller import MainController
from Views.main_view import MainView


class App(QApplication):
    def __init__(self, sys_argv):
        super().__init__(sys_argv)
        self.model = Model()
        self.main_controller = MainController(self.model)
        self.main_view = MainView(self.model, self.main_controller)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App(sys.argv)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**model.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject


class Model(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.directory = ""

    def get_directory(self):
        return self.directory

    def set_directory(self, directory):
        self.directory = directory
```

**main_view.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMenu, QSystemTrayIcon, QMainWindow, QFileDialog
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from Controllers.recorder import Recorder


class MainView(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, model, main_controller):
        super().__init__()

        self._model = model
        self._main_controller = main_controller

        # UI
        icon = QtGui.QIcon("icon24x24.png")
        menu = QMenu()
        start_action = menu.addAction("Start Recording")
        stop_action = menu.addAction("Stop Recording")
        self.tray = QSystemTrayIcon()
        self.tray.setIcon(icon)
        self.tray.setContextMenu(menu)
        self.tray.show()

        start_action.triggered.connect(self.start_app)
        stop_action.triggered.connect(self.stop_app)

        self.recordThread = Recorder()

    def start_app(self):
        directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory")
        self._main_controller.set_directory(directory)
        self.start_thread()

    def start_thread(self):
        self.recordThread.start()

    def stop_app(self):
        self.recordThread.terminate()
        QApplication.instance().quit()
        print("app stopped")
```

**main_controller.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject


class MainController(QObject):

    def __init__(self, model):
        super().__init__()
        self._model = model

    def set_directory(self, directory):
        self._model.set_directory(directory)
```

**recorder.py**

```
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QTimer, pyqtSignal
from Model.model import Model


class Recorder(QThread):

    job_done = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self._model = Model()

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("I am the loop")
            print(self._model.get_directory())
            # time.sleep(4 - time.time() % 4)
            QThread.sleep(4)
            print("now is {}".format(time.time()))
        self.job_done.emit()
```

I've tried using various style, including Qthread, QObject, pyqtsignal according to various tutorial. but nothing works for me. It either just print "I am the loop" then exit. or print

```
I am the loop
Fatal Python error: could not acquire lock for <_io.BufferedWriter name='<stdout>'> at interpreter shutdown, possibly due to daemon threads

Thread 0x00007f5d1bfff700 (most recent call first):
  File "/App/Controllers/recorder.py", line 20 in run

Current thread 0x00007f5d3458f700 (most recent call first):
Aborted
```

Thank you

Comment: show  `main_controller.py`

Comment: Oh my, I've add it.

Comment: The only mistake I see is that you are creating 2 models instead of sharing, to correct this change: **Recorder.py** `def __init__(self):` to `def __init__(self, model):`; `self._model = Model()` to `self._model = model` . **main_view.py**: `self.recordThread = Recorder()` to `self.recordThread = Recorder(model)`

Comment: How are you running the application? in the terminal or in some IDE?

Comment: I have [corrected](https://gist.github.com/azzamsa/bb7b2357ebeeb4e7a092eafb6ec6ef04) according to your suggestion, nothing works. I run the app from terminal.

Comment: I added a suggestion in the gist, try it and indicate me

Comment: I will put any updates in gist. When it's solved, you can post the answer here.

Comment: please try again, it seems I had an error in pasting the code. On the other hand, what version of PyQt5 do you have?

Comment: I've updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code. The app closed immediately after calling `QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory` because it's the nature of Qt.

> Qt is made to exit when all Windows are closed

The app closed because you no longer have any windows. Your app doesn't have any windows but `QSystemTrayIcon()`. Setting `setQuitOnLastWindowClosed()` to False solved the problem.

```
yourApp.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099124/pyqt-exit-qsystemtrayicon-program-after-qmessagebox)